# UIButton in detailCalloutAccessoryView do not fire when touched

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkmapview, mapkit

I have been searched for help on this in quite some time now,  I therefor hope that you guys can help ..please set aside my noob skills in programmering structure  :-)

I have customized my detailCalloutAccessoryView where I loop throuh an array an will make a button which shall call a method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationViewToShow: MKAnnotationView?

    if let title = annotation.title, title == "Din valgte position" {
        return nil
    }
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
    let av = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    let myView = UIView()

    var strSubtitleStringToReplace = ""
    var strSubtitleStringToReplaceWith = ""
    var uibuttonYCoordinate = 30
    //------------------------------------
    let phoneArray = String(describing: annotation.subtitle).components(separatedBy: "\\r")
    var counter = 0
    for word in phoneArray{
        counter += 1
        if counter > 2 {
            let phoneNumber = word.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"))", with: "")
            strSubtitleStringToReplace += "\r" + phoneNumber
            strSubtitleStringToReplaceWith += "\r"
            let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: uibuttonYCoordinate , width: 100, height: 50))
            button2.setTitle(phoneNumber, for: .normal)
            button2.isExclusiveTouch = true
            button2.backgroundColor = .red
            button2.sizeToFit()

            let attributes2 = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
            let attributedText2 = NSAttributedString(string: button2.currentTitle!, attributes: attributes2)

            button2.setAttributedTitle(attributedText2, for: .normal)
            button2.sizeToFit()
            button2.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button2.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Gill Sans", size: 16.0)
            button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.makeCall), for: .touchUpInside)
            myView.addSubview(button2)
            uibuttonYCoordinate += 20


        }
    }
```

}
I then add the uiview to the annotationview

```
        av.detailCalloutAccessoryView = myView
    av.canShowCallout = true
```

and everything is shown correct .. that will say that the button is shown with the correct info ..

the problem is when I click on the annotation and the detailview is shown and I then touch/click the button, the `MakeCall` is not called .. it's like the it only registers the touches on the detailview .. the funny thing is that if I click anywhere on the map and the detailview is not shown and I then touch/click on the annotation again then the button works as it shall ..

are there anyone who has any idea what is wrong ??

Comment: I can see that I both have a gestureRecognizer and a addTarget in the same code section .. it's a typo .. on or the other is not in the code, I just don't know how to update the section here in stackoverflow .. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: There is an edit button under your tags for you to edit your code block.  Where are you setting up this loop? Perhaps self is referencing `myView`, or `detailCalloutAccessoryView`, rather than wherever you added the selector `makeCall`. Or, the tap gesture recognizer may be overriding makeCall. You only should have one. Take the one you don't want out. Or maybe there is some sort of view over the buttons, which is why you can hit it after the detailView is not shown.

Comment: I have changed the original post so you can see the complete function ..